# "each + singular " or "each + plural"

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural

> 1. The server is connected to each PC in the class via **cables**.
> 2. The server is connected to each PC in the class via **a cable**.

I would like to know whether the two sentences listed above I created have different meanings.

Specifically, I think the first means each PC is connected to the server via two or more cables while the second means each PC is connected to the server via a single cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were several cables from each PC to the server you would certainly use the first.

If there was just one cable that linked all the PCs to the server then you would use the second (I'm not sure if that is possible)

You could probably use either in the normal situation of "one cable per PC", but *singular sounds better*, because you specifically say "... each PC...". This means that you are considering each PC separately, and there is only one cable for one PC.

If you said "The server is connected to the PCs by cables" I'd prefer the plural.